# How to get user preferences path from blender

Tags: python, scripting, path

How can I get the the user preferences path from blender, on windows system the path is `%appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.74\config` I want to get this path from blender using python on any system.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using: `bpy.utils.resource_path('USER')`

eg:

```
import os
import bpy

user_path = bpy.utils.resource_path('USER')
config_path = os.path.join(user_path, "config")
```

- Or on Linux:
  `/home/user_name/.config/blender/3.4`
- On ms-windows will return:
  `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.4`

See: [bpy.utils.resource_path](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/bpy.utils.html#bpy.utils.resource_path) api docs